# Do exponential functions grow faster than logarithmic?

Tags: time-complexity

For example:

$f(n) = n(log_2 n)^4$ vs $g(n) = n^{1/3}$

Does f(n) grow slower than g(n) as a general rule, even for decimal exponents? I tried doing a limit test but symbolab limit calculator is saying that Steps are currently not supported for this problem.

I graphed them over a large range and it does appear that g(n) grows asymptotically faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confused about the definition of Big O - graphing `f(n)` and `g(n)` shows `f(n)` surpassing `g(n)` at nearly every scale.

`O(f(n)) > O(g(n)` because `g(n)` is a fractional power polynomial, which is by definition sublinear (if you linearly plug numbers into a square root, cube root, etc., the rate at which the output increases decreases with each successive computation). `g(n)` is a "n log star n" polynomial meaning it follows the form of a log to a power multiplied by n. The rate of growth of these types of functions far exceeds fractional polynomials and its not hard to see why - n is a term of the function, so we know its *at least* linear.

Here's a helpful resource: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities